# Use jquery in the javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bellow I show some example. How I can add some jquery expression into onCalculate() function.

```js
var obj = {
    id: '',
    onCalculate: function () {
       var _date = $("#date").val();  //jquery expression doesn't work here
        // how I can do it?
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by *jquery expression*?

Comment: What code you have tried? What error message is shown?

Comment: gurvinder372, I'd like to call something like this var _date = $("#date").val();

Comment: Your idea is to write a function with the jquery expression?

Comment: Triet Pham, yep. What do you think about it?

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Comment: I don't understand. But now works!

Comment: Thank you all of them for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can call function like this. See working snippet.

```js
var obj = {
  id: '',
  onCalculate: function() {
    var _date = $("#date").val(); //jquery expression doesn't work here
    // how I can do it?
    console.log(_date);
  }
};
$("#date").keyup(function() {
  obj.onCalculate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='date' />
```

Comment: Thank a lot.Validate answer if helpful for future. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks, Have a nice day!